# How to edit a existing a QR code

Tags: qr-code, google-forms, editing

i created a qr code for a simple google form response url . and printed it as a image 
Now can i change the url without changing the image because the image is laminated , is there any way to edit a existing qr code image without altering the image itself

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The data is encoded in the image. In the future you could use a forwarding service (like tinyurl or goo.gl), they might enable you to edit the address it is forwarded to.

Comment: How to use a forwarding service , is there a article or tutorials i can use ,

Comment: There are several url shorteners. You'll be looking for one which is editable. I don't think stackoverflow is the place to post an extensive comparison, so I'd encourage you to do some research. Try googling something like "url shortener with edit". I was able to find a whole bunch, including [tiny.cc](http://tiny.cc/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the url but you can put a html redirection on the actual destination page.

Sometime a picture is worth than a thousand words... http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2013/04/02/true-story-toujours-utiliser-une-url-intermediaire/?setLocale=1